# The method getClip() is undefined for the type AudioSystem

Tags: java

This problem happens when I would like to use AudioSystem.getClip()

The problem is that, it cannot resolve the method getClip().

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public void play1()
{
    
    try {

        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("recod_1.wav").getAbsoluteFile());

        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

        clip.open(audioInputStream);

        clip.start();

    } catch(Exception ex) {

        System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");

        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
    
    
}
```

Everything else has no error, just that one.

I realized that the getClip() method came since the version 1.5. I don't know this is the version of what but it is stated on this link that the getClip method has been affected. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html

I guess that if I update my javax jar file (because I am using an external jar file for javax.sound.sampled) I can fix the problem. But I don't find a newer version of this jar file anywhere else (tritonus-share-0.3.7-2.jar)

Comment: Could you please edit the code to add your imports as well...

Comment: I've changed the code so that it also has the imports.

Comment: What IDE are you using to build this code? What is the Java version used to build it?

Comment: The IDE I am using is eclipse. I need to use it as I want to create GUI as well. 
The version of Java looks like to be java11. I can see that the JRE System Library uses java 11 openjdk amd64.